# Angular2 add structual directive from typestipt to the DOM element

Tags: angular

Is there any way to add a directive to an ElementRef from directive class in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, directives can't be added/removed dynamically.

Directives can only be added by static HTML that matches its selector.